# Onblur blocking <a href>

Tags: javascript, onclick, onblur

I have a simple menu that is opened when clicked on. The problem is the link that is not opened. It's blocked by the onblur event.

HTML:

```
<div id="x1" onclick="dropdown(this); return false;" onblur="dropdownclose(this); return  false;">

<ul class="dropi">
<li>Click here
<ul id="x1menu" class="sub">
<li> <a href="page.php" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if(event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); }">LINK</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>

 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function dropdown(obj)
{
var x = document.getElementById(obj.id+'menu').style.display; 
if(x=='none' || x=='') {
document.getElementById(obj.id+'menu').style.display='block';
}
else if(x=='block') {
document.getElementById(obj.id+'menu').style.display='none';
}
return false;
}


function dropdownclose(obj)
{
var x = document.getElementById(obj.id+'menu').style.display;

if(x=='block') {
document.getElementById(obj.id+'menu').style.display='none';
}
return false;
}
```

After looking at previous questions on stackoverflow I found out that

```
 onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if(event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); }"
```

cancels the onclick"" event of the first div. But the onblur event still blocks the link. Is there a solution for this ?

**EDIT**

Seems to be working in Chrome and not in IE. Any alternative or solution for this ?

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2M4AW/

Comment: @j08691 here is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/2M4AW/3/

Comment: And in your fiddle, what isn't happening that you want to happen?

Comment: @j08691 if you click edit or delete, they don't work.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome & Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, didn't think about a browser problem. I'm using IE now.

Comment: Do you know an alternative or solution for this so that it supports all majors browsers?